# When the data is big, How can I cache data from cassandra to spark?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I take some data from cassandra to spark, when the data is big enough and cannot cache in memory one time ,I have to use spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb to set how big the data one time the machine can get.But I also want to cache the data for more time using ,The code likes this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CassandraLogAnalyse")
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xxx")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "xxx")
  .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "xxx")
  .set("spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb",'512')
//Select Data from cassandra
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val loggly_http_in = sc.cassandraTable("loggly", "http_in").select("uid", "cjj_id", "request_uri", "request_body").where("app_context = ? and log_time > ?", "news", batch_time)

loggly_http_in.cache()

val rdd1 = loggly_http_in.map(...).filter(...)......
val rdd2 = loggly_http_in.map(...).filter(...)......
```

Is it correct?
If it's correct, how it works?
when it's wrong, what's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` setting has nothing to do with caching. This setting determines how big each Spark partition is going to be. If you set it too large, you may get too few tasks and some of your nodes may remain unused. If you set it too low, you'll get more overhead from task scheduling.

Spark can cache multiple partitions of an RDD (and multiple RDDs). So, when you call `cache()`, this will try to cache as many RDD partitions as it can find free memory for. If you need to cache more than it is actually caching, the only way is to allocate more Spark cluster memory to your application.

Your use of `cache` looks good.

Don't forget that you can also cache any transformed RDD. E.g. caching an RDD after filtering will probably require less memory than caching the original RDD you fetched from Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks,I also have a question, This page [link](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md) said "This method ensures a single C* partition request will always create a single Spark task. where clauses with an in will also generate a single Spark Partition." If I use "where" and return only one partition, Can spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb do anything ? or I must change the structure of cassandra and return more partitions,only in this way spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb can work?

Comment: If you return a single Cassandra partition, then it cannot be split, because it "occupies" only one token on the ring. The connector splits the table by tokens. Splitting a single partition is theoretically possible basing on the clustering column range selection, but we haven't found a way to do that reliably and universally for all data models. There is also not much to gain here, as the highest data-local parallelism you could get from a single partition would be equal to the replication factor only.